rsync dry-run to determine whether there is enough space on the destination drive
I'd like to write current data from a failing drive (some data loss due to a few defective sectors) to a drive with an old backup (data since has been reorganized and grown).
Piling the current data on top to ensure nothing is lost would result in duplicate chaos, but just to see whether it would fit I ran (locally):
rsync -avxHAWXSn --numeric-ids --info=progress2 /source/ /dest/
...
sent 56.348.988 bytes  received 3.074.241 bytes  31.267,16 bytes/sec
total size is 3.141.311.295.225  speedup is 52.863,36 (DRY RUN)

And now cannot interpret the output.
Why has rsync sent more than it received?
Is total size the source size or the transferred size?

Sent is larger than received because more files and metadata need to
be sent than need to be received.
Total size is the number of bytes you would have had to transmit
without rsync.
Speedup is the ratio between the total size and what has actually
been transferred.
Reference :
Rsync Output explanation.

So only 3 MB received are new data? That can't be right, even if rsync would detect moved files.

The received data includes also the metadata about folders and files, for comparison with the local folder. There is no information about the percentage of metadata and file-data.
